# Class inheritance in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Why are numbers being returned as an array?

```
class Employee
  def initialize(n,i,ph,ad)
    @number = n, @id = i , @phone = ph, @adress =ad
  end
end
class Getemploy < Employee
  def get_data
    return "The employee number is : #{@number} with id : #{@id} with phone #{@phone} with adress: #{@adress}"
  end
end

puts Getemploy.new("1","2","3","4").get_data
# => The employee number is : ["1", "2", "3", "4"] with id : 2 with phone 3 with adress: 4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour is introduced by assignment expressions, not inheritance. When you type:

```
@number = n, @id = i , @phone = ph, @adress =ad
```

What really means is

- Assign `ad` to `@address`
- Assign `ph` to `@phone`
- Assign `i` to `@id`
- Assign [`n`, the result of assigning `i` to `id`, which is `i`, the result of assigning `ph` to `phone`, which is `ph`, the result of assigning `ad` to `address`, which is `ad`] to `number`, which is a list.

So, the fix that problem, you will need to assign the properties individually, like so.

```
@number = n
@id = i 
@phone = ph
@adress = ad
```

Edit: you can also be smart and do a [destructured assignment](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Operators#1._Assignment), like so...

```
@number , @id , @phone , @adress = [n, i, ph, ad]
```

Comment: Thanks! helped alot

Answer (score 3):

> Why is number being returned as an array?

You assign multiple values to `@number` in your `Employee#initialize` method. The way Ruby represents multiple values is as an `Array`.

IOW:

```
foo = 1, 2, 3
# => [1, 2, 3]
```